# Error al momento de validar un usuario en mi pagina web (php)!

Tags: php, mysql, login, hosting

quisiera realizar una consulta, lo que pasa es que estoy realizando una pagina web sobre denuncias y ya la tengo almacenada en un hosting, pero al momento de loguear un usuario, ese proceso pasa por un validar el cual no me funciona correctamente, ya que cuando el usuario introduce sus datos, debería mandarlo al menú principal de la pagina, pero no lo hace se queda en el validar (trabado, en blanco) ¿A que se deberá ese problema?

Les dejo el codigo de validar.php:

```
<?php

    //include("connect_db.php");

    //$miconexion = new connect_db;

    session_start();

    require("connect_db.php");

    $username = $_POST['mail'];

    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    //la variable $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");

    $sql2  =mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$username'");

    if($f2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)){

        if($pass == $f2['pasadmin']){

            $_SESSION['id'] = $f2['id'];

            $_SESSION['user'] = $f2['user'];

            $_SESSION['rol'] = $f2['rol'];

            echo '<script>alert("BIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR")</script> ';

            echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";

        }
    }

    $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$username'");

    if($f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

        if($pass==$f['password']){

            $_SESSION['id']=$f['id'];

            $_SESSION['user']=$f['user'];

            $_SESSION['rol']=$f['rol'];

            header("Location: Bienvenido.php");
        }else{

            echo '<script>alert("CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA")</script> ';

            echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>"; 
        }
    }else{

        echo '<script>alert("ESTE USUARIO NO EXISTE, PORFAVOR REGISTRESE PARA PODER INGRESAR")</script> ';

        echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";

    }

?>
```

Demostración que pagina queda en blanco después del logueo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo comunicas tu formulario de logueo con el código de validación de **PHP**? Entiendo que lo haces por medio de un `submit` y un `action` en el `<form>` pero no queda del todo claro. De ser así, ¿el código de validación se encuentra en otro documento distinto al del formulario de logueo?

Comment: Cuando la pantalla se queda en blanco es por un error. ¿Que te dice el log?

Answer (score 0):

Considera el uso de `filter_input();` ejemp. para recibir `$_POST` entre otras

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
```

Así mismo verifica que recibes las Variables anteriores
una variable como `$_POST["email"]` la verificas así podría ser

```
print_r(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
```

Si es array:

```
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
```

---

Probablemente lo sepas son buenas prácticas recordarlas.

Debes declarar las variables que usarás: `$f` y `$f2` son actualmente **empty**! por lo cual no habrá ninguna acción no funcionara.

Prueba que recibes dichas variables ejemplo :

```
  if(isset($_POST['email']){
              echo $_POST['email'];
    }
```

En el select recomendaría usar la siguiente instrucción...

```
$sql2  =mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT email, pass, etc FROM login WHERE email = $email AND pass=$pass");

              $FoundUser= mysql_num_rows($sql2);
echo $FoundUser // eliminar despues de comprobar
              if ($FoundUser==1) {
                 #...que hacer si existe el usuario y pass
              }
```

***para realizar varias consultas debes***

```
// Liberar resultados
mysql_free_result($sql2);

// Cerrar la conexión
mysql_close($sql2);
```

hacer un login podría ser un pequeño infierno por la seguridad que debes establecer recomiendo usar PDO es mas sencillo.

en realidad no ofreces muchos datos y los que ofreces no funcionaran...

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el primer bloque de validacion no tiene sentido porque parece que esta preguntando dos veces la validacion de usuario, tambien hay un error, estas comparando un campo if($pass == $f2['pasadmin']) y abajo luego comparas if($pass==$f['password']), debes revisar en la tabla cual es el campo correcto!, quitando ese detalle el codigo deberia correr, he realizado una prueba con tu codigo y parece que el problema esta en la parte de la conexion.

Archivo: connect_db.php

```html
<?php

  // parametros de conexion
  $host ="localhost";
  $user ="grafimar_admin";
  $password ="anybody2015"; 
  $database = "pruebas";

  $mysqli=mysqli_connect($host, $user , $password , $database);
        // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else 
    {
        echo "<br> Conexion Exitosa!";
    }
  
?>
```

Archivo: validar.php

```html
<?php

    session_start();
    require("connect_db.php");
    $username = $_POST['mail'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$username'");
    
    if($f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        if($pass==$f['password']){
                $_SESSION['id']=$f['id'];
                $_SESSION['user']=$f['user'];
                $_SESSION['rol']=$f['rol'];
                header("Location: Bienvenido.php");
        }else{
                echo '<script>alert("CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA")</script> ';
                echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>"; 
        }
    }else{
                echo '<script>alert("ESTE USUARIO NO EXISTE, PORFAVOR REGISTRESE PARA PODER INGRESAR")</script> ';
                echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";
    }
?>
```

(es para el login)
Archivo: index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="validar.php" method="post">
        <label>email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mail">
        <label>pass:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" value="ENTRADA">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

(la entrada de usuario)
Archivo: Bienvenido.php

```html
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<h1>Bienvenido</h1>
<?php
    echo '<br>' . $_SESSION['id'];
    echo '<br>' . $_SESSION['user'];
    echo '<br>' . $_SESSION['rol'];
?>
```

Con este codigo si funciona la validacion. y muestra un aviso cuando el usuario no existe o la clave es incorrecta. (espero que te sirva)

La estructura de la tabla que use es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]